# Android: Button's match_parent doesn't work inside Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I am working on updating my Android App Uno Calculator, but there seems to be an issue in which the + and - buttons do not occupy the `LinearLayout`'s width. This is unexpected, because I have set the properties of both buttons to have `match_parent` height. Below is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right|top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff989898">

        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button1HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button2HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button3HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlusHRegular"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/butonMinusHRegular"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="("
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLeftParenHRegular"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button4Hregular"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter"
             />

        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button5Hregular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button6HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimesHRegular"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter"
             />

        <Button
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSlashHRegular"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text=")"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonRightParenHRegular"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button7HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:id="@+id/button8HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button9HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="+/-"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlusMinusHRegular"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrecentHRegular"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="^"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:id="@+id/buttonHPowerRegular"
            android:background="#ff989898"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:id="@+id/button0HRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="."
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDotHRegular"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

        <Button
            android:text="Clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonClearHRegular"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="clear" />

        <Button
            android:text="="
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEqualsHRegular"
            android:background="#fffdb64b"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="displayResult" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="Mode"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:id="@+id/buttonModeHRegular"
            android:background="#ffb2b2b2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="modeMenu" />

        <Button
            android:text="Uno"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/buttonUnoHRegular"
            android:background="#ffb2b2b2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="unoMenu" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editPRegular"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:text="X"
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:background="@drawable/circlebutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="deleteCharacter"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editPRegular">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/questionButton"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are they `match_parent` when all the other buttons are `wrap_content`? Also, using `match_parent` inside of a parent that uses `wrap_content` doesn't have predictable results -- how is the parent supposed to wrap a child that wants to match the parent size, and how does a child match a parent that wants to wrap its children?

Comment: Even if I set all to match_parent, it doesn't work. I don't know what to set for the height of the parent either.

Comment: Perhaps then you should include an image of what you want and an image of what it's currently doing.

Comment: In `LinearLayout` you used orientation twice use it only once.

Comment: what exactly you want your layout to look like? Sharing an image of the required layout would be helpful in solving problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to make the unity. It's not a problem in + and -. Problem is in * and /.

> android:fontFamily="serif"

```
<Button
        android:text="*"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight=".16667"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTimesHRegular"
        android:background="#ff989898"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
         />

    <Button
        android:text="/"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16667"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSlashHRegular"
        android:background="#ff989898"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter" />
```